# What is the meaning of plane of cleavage in scalp tissue expander implants?

Tags: implant, scalp

According to my professor tissue expander implants are implanted subaponeurotically because of the **Easy plane of cleavage** and also as it is Avascular and [this article](https://doctorlib.info/surgery/plastic/31.html) also mentions the same thing.

> Deep to the galea lies the loose areolar layer, a relatively avascular
> plane also known as the subaponeurotic layer, subgaleal fascia, or
> innominate fascia. It enables the layers above it (skin, subcutaneous
> connective tissue, and galea) to slide as a unit over the cranium. As
> such, this layer is easily dissected and is often the plane of
> cleavage in avulsion or scalping injuries

What does plane of cleavage means in this context?

Answer (score 3):

When you look up "plane of cleavage definition" online, you most often get the definition within Crystallography, [such as](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/cleavage+plane).

> Plane along which a crystalline substance may be split

Applying this to surgical procedures, you will be talking about places where splitting can occur, vertically or horizontally.